# Rotate an Image

Tags: code-golf, image-processing

This challenge is simple: Take a path to an `png` image file as input and overwrite that file with a copy of itself rotated 90 degrees clockwise. You may assume that the file has dimensions of 128x128 pixels. You may not use image metadata modifications (like Exif) to rotate the image; the pixels themselves must be transformed.

### Examples

Input:

[image: A cat]

Output:

[image: A weird cat]

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins.

Comment: Can the program take in the PNG as a file or buffer instead of a path, and output a modified file?

Comment: @Jacob I think this suggestion ignores one of the main part of competition "overwrite the file"

Comment: Is a HTTP PUT an acceptable method of "overwriting"?

Comment: @qarz That depends on the behavior of the server; if the server actually overwrites the file then yes, it does.

Answer (score 12):

## Bash/ImageMagick, 21 bytes

```
mogrify -rotate 90 $1
```

Conveniently this command overwrites the source file, and does not need the image to be of any specific dimensions.

Answer (score 10):

## [AutoHotkey](https://Autohotkey.com) + MSPaint, 77 Bytes

```ahk
f(s){
run mspaint %s%
sleep 999
click 189,116
sleep 200
click 26,13
send ^s
}
```

Autohotkey is not a language that lends itself to golfing very well, though it is uniquely very good at pretending to be a user.

This simply opens paint with the target image, clicks the Rotate, then 90 degrees buttons, then presses CTRL+S to save the image.

[Video of it Running](https://i.gyazo.com/14731a8cdf526983aea0e97d90c8308a.mp4)

Comment: You can send keys instead of clicking, `send !hror^s`

Comment: I love this. This is one of those things that would probably be a new standard loophole if it were more space-efficient, but it's not, so it remains a fun novelty that occasionally shows up and is occasionally surprisingly small.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://python.org/) + [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org), <s>64</s> 59 bytes

```python
from PIL.Image import*
open(p:=input()).rotate(-90).save(p)
```

*-5 thanks to @tsh*

##### Commented

```python
from PIL.Image import*         # Import module
open(                          # Open an image
    p:=input()                 # Input the filename and store in p
).rotate(                      # Rotate the image
    -90                        # -90 degrees anti-clockwise
                               # (= 90 degrees clockwise)
).save(p)                      # And save it back in the original file
```

Comment: Maybe you can `from PIL.Image import*` and then `open(p:=...`

Comment: @tsh yes, you're right! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 8 bytes

```
YiIX!GYG
```

Unfortunately the online compilers cannot load/save images so [here](https://matl.io/?code=1%3A100+10+e+XJ++%25+Sample+image%0A%27Original%27D%0AlYG++++++++++++%25+Display+the+sample+image%0AlY.++++++++++++%25+Pause+for+1+second%0AXx%27Rotated%27D%0AJIX%21+++++++++++%25+Rotate+the+image%0AlYG++++++++++++%25+Display+the+rotated+image&inputs=&version=22.7.4) is a demo that uses an image defined within the interpreter itself.

**Explanation**

```
     % Implicitly grab the first input (the file path) as a string
Yi   % Read in the image
IX!  % Rotate 270 degrees counter-clockwise
G    % Grab the file path again
YG   % Write the rotated image to this file
```

Answer (score 7):

## NodeJS + [JIMP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp), 74 bytes

```
require('jimp').read(n=process.argv[2]).then(x=>x.rotate(270,!1).write(n))
```

The path to image must be passed as third arg:

```
node filename.js imageSrc.png
```

### UPD 87 -> 84

Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) for the [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257892/rotate-an-image/257903?noredirect=1#comment569877_257903) to reduce bytes count

### UPD 84 -> 74

Thanks to [Jacob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108687/jacob) for the [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257892/rotate-an-image/257903?noredirect=1#comment569884_257903) to reduce bytes count

Comment: Aren't you supposed to take input rather than just hard-coding it as `c.png`?

Comment: @TheThonnu Yes, you are right!

Comment: You can get rid of the `(async()=>{...})()` if you use Node16 or newer (top-level await)

Comment: @Jacob I already tried it but it doesn't work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4peI.png

Comment: @EzioMercer You can use dynamic import () instead. `await import(“jimp”)`

Comment: @Jacob It still doesn't work. Can you please test on your computer and then provide complete command?

Comment: When I get the chance I will, busy at the moment;

Comment: @Jacob I found a way how to use what you wanted. You need to use `mjs` instead of `js` because `top level await` available only in module. In modules you can't use `require` you need to use `import`. To make it oneliner you need to use dynamic import i.e. `await import()`. Then you need to specify the `index.js` file in library when importing i.e. you can't use `await import('jimp')` you need to use `await import('jimp/dist/index.js')` and then get `default` property

Comment: @Jacob So the final command will look like this: `(await (await import('jimp/dist/index.js')).default.read(process.argv[2])).rotate(270,!1).write(process.argv[2])`  and it is `112` bytes which more than current one

Comment: `let n=process.argv[2];import j from"jimp";(await j.read(n)).rotate(270,!1).write(n)` is 83 bytes (`.mjs`)

Comment: `require("jimp").read(n=process.argv[2]).then(x=>x.rotate(270,!1).write(n))` is 74 bytes (regular `.js` file)

Comment: @Jacob I feel stupid :) Thank you! 10 bytes OMG...

Answer (score 7):

## MacOS [zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) + [sips](https://ss64.com/osx/sips.html), 13

```bash
sips -r 90 $1
```

[sips (Scriptable Image Processing System)](https://ss64.com/osx/sips.html) is a lesser-known built-in command-line utility for image manipulation.  Confusingly, nothing to do with [SIP (System Integrity Protection)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection).

---

## MacOS [zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) alias + [sips](https://ss64.com/osx/sips.html), 10

```bash
sips -r 90
```

Create the alias with `alias r=sips -r 90`, then run with `r test.png`.

Comment: Do you actually need the ```$1```?  If the input is given as a command-line argument, isn't the 'program' just ```sips -r 90``` (10 bytes)?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen To my knowledge, there is no way to implicitly do this without providing a positional parameter.  In some CG asnwers, a script can read from STDIN - the stream gets piped to the first command in the script that reads it.  But in this case the input is the filename, as we need to both read from and write to the input filename.  Also, `sips` doesn't appear to read from STDIN

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your explanation: typing ```sips -r 90 2iORu.png``` on my Mac seems to rotate the image file "2iORu.png" and overwrite the original (without using zsh).  Isn't that the objective?

Comment: If you're typing `sips -r 90 2iORu.png` (presumably into the terminal), then you are using the shell, which `zsh` by default on modern MacOS.  Thus my answer is a `zsh` shell script (that could be saved as a script file).  Am I missing something?  If I create a zsh script file with the content `sips -r 90`, it doesn't do what is required.

Comment: I got it now - thanks - the "that could be saved as a file" bit is what I was missing...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I suppose one could submit an answer in the form of a shell alias `alias r='sips -r 90'`, which may be run as `r test.png` then claim that the alias is only 10 bytes long... hmm, not a bad idea for this challenge actually

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 64 bytes

Anonymous prefix lambda.

```apl
{b.MakePNG⎕NREPLACE,⍨⍵⎕NTIE-≡b.CBits←⌽⍉'CBits'⍎⍨'b'⎕WC'Bitmap'⍵}
```

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is denoted `⍵`:

`'b'⎕WC'Bitmap'⍵` create a Bitmap `b` from the file

`'CBits'⍎⍨` extract the **C**olour **Bits** from that

`⍉` transpose

`⌽` mirror

`b.CBits←` update `b`'s Colour Bits to that value

`≡` get the array nesting depth of that (returns 1)

`-` negate (returns −1)

`⍵⎕NTIE` use that as file handle to tie the file (returns −1)

`,⍨` self-concatenate (we need a list of file handle and start position, where −1 means current position, i.e. at the start of the file)

`b.MakePNG⎕NREPLACE` replace the file contents with a render of `b` to PNG file contents

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `image.processing.rotation`, 52 bytes

```
[ dup load-image 90 rotate swap save-graphic-image ]
```

Testing the function in Factor's REPL:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://python.org/) + [opencv-python](https://opencv.org/), <s>84</s> 62 bytes

```python
import cv2
cv2.imwrite(p:=input(),cv2.rotate(cv2.imread(p),0))
```

[image: Screenshot]

*-22 thanks to @Stef*

Unfortunately for some reason when I do `from cv2 import*` it just doesn't work:

[image: Screenshot]

##### Commented

```python
import cv2               # Import module
cv2.imwrite(             # Write to a file:
    p:=input()           #  Get the filename as input and store in p
    cv2.rotate(          #  A rotated version of:
        cv2.imread(p),   #   The contents of p
        0                #   Rotated 90 degrees clockwise
))                       # Close the parentheses
```

Comment: It looks like `cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE` is just an enum with value 0. So you could just do `cv2.imwrite(p:=input(),cv2.rotate(cv2.imread(p),0))
`

Comment: BTW the `from cv2 import*` version works for me. Have you tried with a linebreak instead of a `;`?

Comment: @Stef yeah I did, it still didn't work. I'll update it with the `0` later.

Answer (score 4):

## Python + Pygame, 77 bytes

```py
from pygame import*
image.save(transform.rotate(image.load(a:=input()),90),a)
```

Guess in terms of golfiness [PIL/Pillow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257899/91213) > Pygame > [OpenCV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257897/91213)

Comment: Now Pillow > OpenCV > Pygame

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 46 bytes

```julia
using Images
~f=save(f,imrotate(load(f),π/2))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 58 bytes

```powershell
%{$p=[Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_);$p|% Ro* 1;$p.Save($_)}
```

Input comes from the pipeline.

TIO won't work, what with the file, so the following assumes the cat above was downloaded to C:\Temp.

Try it in a PS 7 Console:

```powershell
$path = 'C:\Temp\2iORu.png'
$path |
%{$p=[Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_);$p|% Ro* 1;$p.Save($_)}
Invoke-Item $path
```

## Windows PowerShell, 78 bytes

The System.Drawing assembly must be loaded, which costs 20 bytes as compared to Core.

```powershell
%{Add-Type -A *.*wing;$p=[Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_);$p|% Ro* 1;$p.Save($_)}
```

Try it in a Windows PowerShell console:

```powershell
$path = 'C:\Temp\2iORu.png'
$path |
%{Add-Type -A *.*wing;$p=[Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_);$p|% Ro* 1;$p.Save($_)}
Invoke-Item $path
```

Pretty straightforward:
Starts the `%` cmdlet (alias for ForEach-Object)
Adds the assembly System.Drawing (not required in PS Core).
Loads the image file from the pipeline (in `$_`) into $p.
Then a bit of golfing can take place: `$p|% Ro* 1` pipes the image to % (ForEach-Object) and calls the image's method RotateFlip(RotateFlipType), with 1 being Rotate90FlipNone.
Then the image gets saved to the original location.
Invoke-Item shows the image in the default app for .png. You can of course leave out that line and open it with your favorite viewer.

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB/Octave, 33 bytes

```
@(x)imwrite(rot90(imread(x),3),x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 7.4.33 + [WideImage 11.02.09](https://wideimage.sourceforge.net/download/) - 88 bytes

This relies on the WideImage library, which is an old library to manipulate images.

```php
<?php include($x=WideImage)."/$x.php";$x::load($a=$argv[1])->rotate(90)->saveToFile($a);
```

You can use from PHP 5.2.0 to 7.4.33, but I've confirmed it works in 7.4.33 and 5.6.44.

This is meant to be executed from a command line/shell.

It does exactly what the code says: loads an image, rotates by 90º and overwrites the file.

## How to test this

Just follow these simple steps:

- Install PHP 7.4.33
- Create a PHP file *somewhere* convenient
- Put the code in that file
- Download [WideImage](https://wideimage.sourceforge.net/download/) - DO NOT DOWNLOAD THE GITHUB VERSION
- Extract the `lib` folder
- Rename it to `WideImage`

To run it, just execute something like `php -f file.php image.png`.

Answer (score 0):

## [`feh`](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) image viewer, 1

`feh` is an image viewer for the Unix [X window system](https://www.x.org/wiki/), first developed in 1999.

```
>
```

From [linux.com](https://www.linux.com/news/cli-magic-feh-image-viewing):

> Type > to rotate an image 90 degrees clockwise, and < to rotate it 90 degrees counterclockwise. Your changes are immediately saved to the file.